# codewars Create a function that returns the CSV representation of a two-dimensional numeric array. javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second century - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200 ( javascript ).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since centuries are numbers then hopefully they don't contain commas `,` that needs to be escaped, you can just `join` the array items (the outer ones and the inner ones) into a CSV.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 100],
  [101, 102, 103, 200],
]

var csv  = arr.map(function (century) {
  return century.join(",");
}).join("\n");

console.log(csv)
```